# How to calculate this composite partial derivative?

Tags: partial-derivative

I have the expressions :

H = $p^2/2 - 1/(2q^2)$

D = (pq)/2 - Ht

And I want to calculate the Poisson bracket [H,D] and show that it is -H = $-p^2/2 + 1/(2q^2)$

[Here is the definition of a Poisson bracket (here we can drop the i subscript because I'm considering a one-dimensional case)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7UTP.png)

It just isn't giving me the result I want to show because, in the terms ∂D/∂p (and ∂D/∂q, but I'll just write the former) I am doing:

∂D/∂p = q/2 - t(∂H/∂p)

and I end up with this extra t term in the end.

I've tried justifying why I should be able to just remove this term but I am not being able to, so I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that
$$\partial_q H=\frac{1}{q^3}$$
$$\partial_p H=p$$
$$\partial_q D=\frac{p}{2}-t\frac{1}{q^3}$$
$$\partial_p D=\frac{q}{2}-tp$$
So
\begin{align}\{H,D\}
&=\frac{1}{q^3}\left(\frac{q}{2}-tp\right)-p\left(\frac{p}{2}-t \frac{1}{q^3}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2q^2}-\frac{tp}{q^3}-\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{tp}{q^3}\\
&=\frac{1}{2q^2}-\frac{p^2}{2}\\
&=-H
\end{align}
Sidenote: to be mathematically correct, this is Hamiltonian mechanics, so everything is a function of the time $t$, generalised coordinate $q$ and generalised momentum $p$, so we are doing the derivatives according to this.

Comment: Oh, I messed up the minus sign in the third step, got it!